# Manually Clone/Copy an instance in Python

Tags: python, copy, clone

I know we have both `copy` and `deepcopy` inside the module `copy`, but I'd like to do it manually...

I started by playing a little with `__dict__` object just to see how can I create instances setting the same attributes that the object to be copied have, and here's the result of my first test:

```
class A(object):
    def F(self):
        print "Test!"

a = A()
x = type('A', (object, ), dict(A.__dict__))
x.F()
```

When executed, the following error appeared:

> TypeError: unbound method F() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

**How could I implement a method/function in Python to clone/copy (recursively) an object?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To manually create a shallow copy of an instance of the user-defined class `A`, you can do

```
a = A()
b = object.__new__(A)
b.__dict__ = a.__dict__.copy()   # or dict(a.__dict__)
```

The call to `object.__new__()` creates a new instance without calling `__init__()`.

Your code constructs a new type object rather than a new instance of `A`.

Implementing a deep copy is much more involved -- you would basically need to reimplement the whole [`copy`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/copy.py) and [`copyreg`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/copy_reg.py) modules.  They are written in Python -- just follow the links to see the source code.

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks for your answer. Any idea of how can I do a deep copy? I think I will have to do the same for every instance inside...

Answer (score 0):

Without answering your "clone/copy" question, your code have a small bug.  My version of your code is:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        print "Test!"

a = A()
a.f()

X = type('A', (object, ), dict(A.__dict__))
x = X()
x.f()
```